# Rails Active Record - Calling Distict Rows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following models

```
influencers (id, name, ..)
influencer_authorizations (id, influencer_id, ... )
influencer_metrics (id, influencer_authorization_id, date, count)
```

The relationships are as follows

```
influencers has_many influencer_authorizations
influencer_authorizations has_many influencer_metrics
```

I want to fetch the count of all the influencer_authorizations in the influencer_metrics with the latest `DATE` and sum to show the total followers of the `influencer`

What am trying

*Finding all the Authorizations IDs*

```
influencer_authorizations = InfluencerAuthorization.where(influencer_id: influencer.id).pluck(:id)
```

Now i am trying to find the latest Date's rows all the `influencer_authorizations` technically for each `influencer_authorizations` it should give back one row whose sum i want to calculate.

```
total_followers = InfluencerMetric.where(influencer_authorization_id: influencer_authorizations).order('metrics_date DESC').first
```

But it returns all the rows right now. The date is tricky as i each `influencer_authorizations` last fetched date can be different at times. So we need the lastest `metrics` records for each `influencer_authorizations`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could this possibly be what you're looking for?

```
Influencer.
  joins(influencer_authorizations: :influencer_metrics).
  select("SUM(influencer_metrics.count) as followers, COUNT(influencer_metrics.id)").
  where(id: influencer.id).
  group("influencer_authorizations.id").
  order("influencer_metrics.metrics_date DESC").
  limit(1)
```

I'm not quite clear on the query that you described, as some of the wording seemed inverted from the schema relationships.  It may be a starting point.

If it happens to not work as expected, try to remove the .limit(1) portion and see what's returned.  We can go from there if you're game.

Comment: Basically i want the total followers of the Influencer. Based on the lastest Crawled data for various authorizations like `facebook` `twitter` etc